# System.Timers.Timer fires second time a few milliseconds later

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

In my application I have a System.Timers.Timer which fires a second time a few milliseconds later.

Declaration of the timer:

```
mRecipeTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);
mRecipeTimer.Start();
mRecipeTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(mRecipeTimer_Elapsed);
```

Timer elapse event:

```
void mRecipeTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    int sync = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref syncPoint, 1, 0);
    if (sync == 0)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = string.Format("timer, started at {0} ({1})", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        Log.Info("Recipe timer elapsed.");
        // some code
        syncPoint = 0;
    }
}
```

And this is what I see in my logs:

```
2012-01-31 11:17:26,797 [timer, started at 1/31/2012 11:17:26 AM (797)] INFO  - Recipe timer elapsed.
2012-01-31 11:17:27,875 [timer, started at 1/31/2012 11:17:27 AM (875)] INFO  - Recipe timer elapsed.
2012-01-31 11:17:56,797 [timer, started at 1/31/2012 11:17:56 AM (797)] INFO  - Recipe timer elapsed.
2012-01-31 11:17:57,875 [timer, started at 1/31/2012 11:17:57 AM (875)] INFO  - Recipe timer elapsed.
```

I allready placed an interlock so that only one action may run at the same time. But unfornately the timer fires its event twice and I don't know why.

Comment: Have you tried using `System.Threading.Timer` instead? I prefer to use that one and never had a problem with it.

Comment: Where are you starting the timer? Are you sure you don't have multiple instances floating around? And why is that interlocked needed? If the timer executes once every 30 seconds, is there a risk that it will call the handler twice in this interval?

Comment: Did you register the Elapsed event handler twice?

Comment: I've changed the post a little, I added the event coupling and start command. As you can see, I start the timer before I add the event handler. The creation and start is done in a background worker.

Comment: @todur i've added the interlock so the elapse event will not be called twice if it's already running. It can happen that the elapse event takes more than 30 seconds (it almost does not happen).

Comment: @Bojo: This looks like it was done in a designer. I suspect you have a designer created eventhandler also. Check the generated code, or clear  it in the designer propertygrid.

Comment: @leppie no I wrote it myself with auto completion from Visual Studio. Futher inspection shows that there may be a second instance...

Comment: I think it is correct to assign the Elapsed event before you start the timer.

Comment: @Bojo: I realise you write the one you posted yourself, it is the other one you do not know that worries me :) Look in the `InitializeComponent()` method in the .Designer.cs file.

Comment: I'll switch the event and the start. @leppie i don't have a .Designer.cs, it is a own controller class.

Answer (score 1):

You can always disable/enable the timer while the event is being processed, i.e.,

```
void mRecipeTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    mRecipeTimer.Enabled = false; //<---- disable

    int sync = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref syncPoint, 1, 0);
    if (sync == 0)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = string.Format("timer, started at {0} ({1})", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        Log.Info("Recipe timer elapsed.");
        // some code
        syncPoint = 0;
    }

    mRecipeTimer.Enabled = true; //<---- enable
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately and luckily it was not that the timer fired twice. It was that the object which contained the timer was instantiated twice.

Comment: I had a similar problem and found out that I could not reset the ElapsedEventHandler